# Using Dynamic Proxies in Java to handle API throttling exceptions

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, throttling

I'm using the AWS SSM client all over the place, and it's difficult for me to add try/catch blocks everywhere and implement the same auto retry mechanism.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! I recently discovered proxies in Java, which I can use to proxy **all** methods in the SSM client, and then pass this proxied instance all over the place. Here's what I came up with:

```
private AWSSimpleSystemsManagement createClient() {
    final AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssm = AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard()
            ...
            ...
            .build();
    return (AWSSimpleSystemsManagement) Proxy.newProxyInstance(ssm.getClass().getClassLoader(),
            new Class[]{AWSSimpleSystemsManagement.class}, (proxy, method, args) -> {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        return method.invoke(ssm, args);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        if (ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e).contains("Rate exceeded")
                                || e.toString().contains("Rate exceeded")) {
                            final long delay = (long) (5_000 * Math.random());
                            logger.warn("AWS is throttling us. Will retry in {} ms", delay);
                            EDUtils.sleep(delay);
                        } else {
                            throw e;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Javadoc for InvocationHandler and for Proxy may be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html